# Why are there no stall angle requirements outlined by regulations like CS-25?

Tags: regulations, easa-regulations

When reading regulations like CS-25, it outlines specific requirements for stall speed such as

**CS 25.103 Stall speed:**

[image]

[Source](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/CS-25_Amdt%203_19.09.07_Consolidated%20version.pdf)

The only mention of angle of attack is in relation to stick pushers.
Is there not something like an angle-of-attack margin that needs to be observed? Could one create a plane that has a very low stall angle of attack provided it meets the stall speed requirements?

Comment: I suspect that the AoA is not particularly relevant because it doesn't control how fast the plane lands. Absolute speed is correlated to safety through many factors, such as the energy involved in a crash, the amount of runway required, the stress on tires, etc... I can't think of how absolute AoA has an equivalent correlation to safety.

Comment: @KennSebesta, I understand what you're saying.
Still, the fact that stick pushers exist that get activated at a certain angle of attack means that there is some safety concern that is tied to angle of attack

Comment: There's no concept of `x` degrees is riskier than `y` degrees for a generic value of `y`. The AoA for a stick pusher to activate is dependent on the wing's airfoil. This is not the case for energy, and thus absolute airspeed.